# SQL Server 2008 Replication Issue

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have a column that was added to the primary database and is being replicated to a secondary database. We are now receiving the following error:

```
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'RI_SystemType' in table 'dbo.R_Information' is specified more than once. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2705)
Get help: http://help/2705
```

Replication is currently failing across the database and we assume that this is the cause. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, rookie mistake. A deployment script also created the new column in the subscriber. Of course, that's the whole point of replication so once we dropped the column from the subscriber, replication created it itself and all was well.

Comment: Which is cool and all, except I've got the same issue, and I did NOT create the column on the subscriber :(